# How to create a jar with external libraries included in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am done with the project which connects to database (MySQL). Now I want to export the project as jar. But I don't know how to include its external dependencies? Is there any way of doing it in Eclipse or should I use any scripts for that?.

Comment: How do you intend to deliver the app. to the end user? A network/internet, a disk or flash drive, ..something else?  Does the app. have a GUI?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

When you export your project as a 'Runnable jar' (Right mouse on project -> Export -> Runnable jar) you have the option to package all dependencies into the generated jar. It also has two other ways (see screenshot) to export your libraries, be aware of the licences when deciding which packaging method you will use.

[image: Package libraries]

The 'launch configuration' dropdown is populated with classes containing a `main(String[])` method. The selected class is started when you 'run' the jar.

Exporting as a runnable jar uses the dependencies on your build path (Right mouse on project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path...). When you export as a 'regular' (non-runnable) jar you can select any file in your project(s). If you have the libraries in your project folder you can include them but external dependencies, for example [maven](/questions/tagged/maven), cannot be included (for maven projects, [search here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=maven%20runnable%20jar%20with%20dependencies)).

Comment: @Joost  : sir, i donot get any option under the launch configuration heading when trying to export a java application as a runnable jar. What could be wrong or missing ?

Comment: Eclipse lists the `main()` methods it knows about. Try running your application once (Right click project, Run As, Java Application) and then export again.

Comment: Anyone know how to do this for a non-runnable jar in eclipse?  There are no options related to 'required libraries'.

Comment: @jb1 Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: My project does not have a main class. Is there a different way to export it?

Comment: If your project does not have main-method (not main class), what do you expect the jar to run?

Comment: @Joost the JAR is loaded by another program

Answer (score 10):

You could use the Export->Java->Runnable Jar to create a jar that includes its dependencies

Alternatively, you could use the [fatjar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/) eclipse plugin as well to bundle jars together

Answer (score 6):

You can right-click on the project, click on export, type 'jar', choose 'Runnable JAR File Export'. There you have the option 'Extract required libraries into generated JAR'.

Answer (score 4):

Personally,

None of the answers above worked for me, I still kept getting NoClassDefFound errors (I am using Maven for dependencies).  My solution was to build using "mvn clean install" and use the "[project]-jar-with-dependencies.jar" that that command creates.  Similarly in Eclipse you can right click the project -> Run As -> Maven Install and it will place the jars in the target folder.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to export all JAR-files of a Java web-project, open the latest generated WAR-file with a ZIP-tool (e.g. 7-Zip), navigate to the /WEB-INF/lib/ folder. Here you will find all JAR-files you need for this project (as listed in "Referenced Libraries").

Answer (score 2):

While exporting your source into a jar, make sure you select runnable jar option from the options. Then select if you want to package all the dependency jars or just include them directly in the jar file. It depends on the project that you are working on.

You then run the jar directly by java -jar example.jar.

Answer (score 2):

To generate jar file in eclipse right click on the project for which you want to generate, Select Export>Java>Runnable Jar File,

[image]

[image]

Its create jar which includes all the dependencies from Pom.xml, But please make sure license issue if you are using third-party dependency for your application.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a standalone (Main method) java project then Not any specific path put all the jars inside the project not any specific path then right click on the project - > export - > Runnable jar --> Select the lunch configuration and Library handeling then choose the radio button option "Package required libraries into generated jar" -- > Finish.

Or

If you have a web project then put all the jars in web-inf/lib folder and do the same step.

Answer (score 1):

Before exporting, click on Buildpath and configure java buildpath and add external jars inside the library. Then try to export as a runnable jar.