# Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver | Eclipse isnt exporting jar

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

again me.

I dont know what the hell isnt working right, but everytime im exporting my Teamspeak Bot wrote in Java, it seems like he dont export the mysql-connector.jar.
Everytime im trying to start my jar, he always tells me that he cant find the MySQL-Driver.

Heres my Code:

[image]

As you can see, the jar file is in the buildpath. When i try running it through Eclipse, everything works fine. Only when im exporting he throws me the Exception.

Hope someone of you can help me.

ndslr

Comment: @Satya if im running it on centos, which lib folder? java lib folder, centos lib/lib64 folder? tried all of them, nothing worked

Comment: How exactly are you exporting your jar?

Comment: show us deploy options; to what @Satya meant is if you are using some sort of container - you need to add `lib` folder that contains all of you jar files on your class path

Comment: @KevinWorkman http://i.imgur.com/dS6blDM.png  Im exporting it as a normal jar with these options.

Comment: @Алексей So you mean i should create a new Folder named "lib" in my project and put the jar there?

Comment: it depends... if you use tomcat or jetty for example then by going into deploy assembly you should indicate what jar you would want to be in the `lib` folder; if on the other hand it is a stand alone app then you should provide a `--classpath` option, if however you can not specify `--classpath` option then you need to add jars into your jar file. Once you can indicate how do you run your app we can help you better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're exporting your jar, your library jar isn't automatically added to the output jar. You would have to specify the classpath when you run it:

```
java -cp "C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\mysql-connector.jar;YourOutputJar.jar" TS3BotMySQL
```

Instead, you have to add the mysql-connector.jar to your output jar. To do this, instead of going to export > jar, go to export > **runnable** jar, and then select "Extract required libraries into generated JAR" or "Package required libraries into generated JAR" at the prompt.

See these related questions for more information:

[How to create a jar with external libraries included in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033603/how-to-create-a-jar-with-external-libraries-included-in-eclipse)

[Eclipse Java; export jar, include referenced libraries, without fatjar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528007/eclipse-java-export-jar-include-referenced-libraries-without-fatjar)

[Generating a Jar in Eclipse including external library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986063/generating-a-jar-in-eclipse-including-external-library)

[How export Java jar from Eclipse with dependencies on other jars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785804/how-export-java-jar-from-eclipse-with-dependencies-on-other-jars)