# JPA works on Eclipse but not on JAR

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jar

I have an issue with a Java program.  When I run the program from Eclipse (Run or Debug) it works fine.  But, when I try to run the exported JAR file it gives me the following error:

> 977  INFO   [main] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 2.4.2
>   The persistence provider is attempting to use properties in the persistence.xml file to resolve the data source. A Java Database Connectivity (JDBC) driver or data source class name must be specified in the openjpa.ConnectionDriverName or javax.persistence.jdbc.driver property. The following properties are available in the configuration: "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl@2655aabb".

I checked that the persistence.xml is in the correct place (src/META-INF) in the JAR file.

This is my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="JPA" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

  <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
  <class>class_name_here</class>
  <class>class_name_here</class>

  <properties>

    <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="unsupported" />

    <!-- Production -->
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://server:port/database" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />

  </properties>
```

*I removed the values from the properties, but in the original file they are there and they are correct (it runs from within Eclipse).

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785804/how-export-java-jar-from-eclipse-with-dependencies-on-other-jars

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I was using option "Package required libraries into generated JAR".  I tried per the instructions in the link and now it is telling me "No persistence providers available for "JPA" after trying the following descovered implementation: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider"

Comment: You've declared OpenJPA as your persistence provider (`<provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>`) but the error mentions EclipseLink (`discovered implementation: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider`) so, which is it? Which JPA implementation is available on the classpath?

Comment: Thanks.  It would be JPA.  I found some  extra libs in my classpath and made some cleanup, but the error is the original.  So far, these are the only 2 libs in my classpath:

mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar
openjpa-all-2.4.2.jar
*There are others that were added through maven but those are for logging and Twitter, nothing related to persistence.

Comment: Try adding OpenJPA and MySQL Connector to Maven dependencies and removing the standalone dependencies from build path

Comment: I already did, the outcome did not change.

Comment: Thanks.  I decided to recreate the project as a new Maven project and that solved the issue (maybe something was stuck or misconfigured in old project).

Answer (score 0):

Recreating the project from scratch solved the issue.