# Eclipse: How to export a .jar file that has a .jar file in the build path

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

I'm trying to make a .jar file to use in future programs, and in the build path of that file, is another .jar file that is a used resource of the program i'm making.

whenever I try to export with Export>Jar File and hit finish, and open my newly created jar with winrar, there is no other file in there, and i get errors when trying to use it.

I've tried going to properties>java build path>order and export, and selected everything, and it still doesnt work! please help me!

This is in eclipse.

Comment: You need to export it as a runnable jar along with all the dependencies checked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033603/how-to-create-a-jar-with-external-libraries-included-in-eclipse

Comment: except that it isnt designed to be runnable. it is going to be a resource in many other projects

Comment: @PulsePanda Then you should really use a build system such as Maven. Those tools are designed specifically to handle collecting all the required libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: just used Fat Jar Plugin[enter link description here](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/)