# Eclipse not exporting libraries

Tags: eclipse, jar, libraries

(In Eclipse) When I right click export and export as a Jar file, it does not package the libraries into the Jar file.  It was exporting the libraries a couple weeks ago and the libraries were going into the Jar file and I'm not sure what changed.

I figured it was Eclipse so I reinstalled the program and imported the workspace with no luck.  I also tried on a completely different machine.

I've moved the libraries into a container in Eclipse and also tried external libraries and none of the libraries are exporting.  The only thing it's exporting is the class files, .claspath, .project, and the manifest.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [you need this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11033670/2749470)

Answer (score 0):

Of course when you post a question you've been working on (for hours) you seem to find the answer 5 minutes later...

The file was not exporting correctly because I chose "JAR file" instead of "Runnable JAR File".