# How can I export jar file from Eclipse with the referenced libraries?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

The title basically says it; I want to export a jar file from Eclipse with all the referenced libraries. I have tried to export it as a runnable jar as well, but it does not have a main method so I'm guessing this won't work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a jar with external libraries included in eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033603/how-to-create-a-jar-with-external-libraries-included-in-eclipse)

Comment: that one is about exporting a runnable jar. Mine does not have main method and therefore I cannot export it as a runnable jar.

Comment: @mrlarseen, ok, I retracted my vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would post this as a comment, but my reputation does not allow.

Can you not just add a blank main method?

Answer (score 2):

Goto File -> Export -> Java -> Jar. Select it to pack all of the referenced libraries.

Comment: I can not see this option in eclipse kepler. Dan you show a screenshot?

Comment: The options I have are:


`Export generate class files and resources`  

`Export all output folders for checked projects` 
 
`Export Java source files and resources`  

`Export refactorings for checked projects`  


I have checked all of them in different combinations and I get the same result.

If I run `jar -tf <name-of-jar>` should the referenced libraries be listed? Or is this not the way to find out?