# ClassNotFound Exception log4j only when running exported executable jar on cmd

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, log4j, classnotfoundexception

I'm successfully running a Java console based program inside eclipse. But when I export external jar it throws me **ClassNotFound** Exception for class **log4j**.
Its working perfectly inside eclipse, but when I execute exported jar with **java -jar filename.jar** it gives me error

[image]

I have also added the external jar of log4j in my eclipse project
[image]

And as well as to my build path, but still no result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check if you have `log4j` dependencies in your exported `jar`. Because you are adding jars in a `Build Path` it might be not present in exported `jar`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033603/how-to-create-a-jar-with-external-libraries-included-in-eclipse) you can find how to include external dependencies in your exported `jar`.