# Unable to set Java Class path properly

Tags: java

I have a newbie question on java; have been unable to set classpath properly. Am missing something very basic and trivial.

I have a jar file. foo.jar, in e:\bar.

This works from command line, when the current directory is e:\bar

```
java -jar foo.jar <params>
```

When I change directory to e:, it starts throwing class not found exceptions. So I set -cp to specify the class path. Whatever I have tried so far, it has failed to work

```
java -cp ".;e:/bar/*;e:/bar/lib/*" -jar bar/foo.jar <params>
java -cp "." -jar bar/foo.jar <params>
....
```

I always get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils$2.run(ClassUtils.java:187)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:171)
        at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDTargetedChain.makeNewInstance(WSDDTargetedChain.java:196)
        at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:310)
        at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:296)
        at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getTransport(WSDDDeployment.java:470)
        at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getTransport(FileProvider.java:282)
        at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getTransport(AxisEngine.java:283)
        at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:179)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2564)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2553)
        at com.ideas.jws.gftservice.GFTMessenger.sendMessage(GFTMessenger.java:1
```

Comment: Since when windows started using '/' as directory separator instead of '\'?

Comment: @zubergu Either one has worked since about 15 years ago (if not more).

Comment: I would recommend you use eclipse to export a Java project combined with the dependency JAR files, then you don't need to set classpath at all , Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033603/how-to-create-a-jar-with-external-libraries-included-in-eclipse

Comment: yeah; you would recommend someone to download this, download that; do this, all to run a program? Seriously?

Comment: At least you try putting the specific JAR file names instead of wild card *, I assume the apache-commons-httpclient is somehow missing its dependencies when you specify *

Comment: Thank you. I stuck with launching the jar from the directory where the jar resided. Trying to launch it from some other directory was proving to be too much of a bother.

Answer (score 0):

`-cp` does not work with `-jar`.

If you know the main class name, then you can work around it by not using `-jar`:

```
java -cp ".;e:/bar/*;e:/bar/lib/*;bar/foo.jar" main.class.name.Here <params>
```

Comment: Thank you. Just tried that. Still same exact error.

Answer (score 0):

As the application jar is dependent of a specific set of jars, one common practice is to have:

```
distribution
 ├─ myapp.jar
 └─ lib
     ├─ libaaa-1.2.3.jar
     └─ libbbb-2-3-4.jar
```

In META-INF/MANIFEST.MF of the application jar one often generates a `Class-Path: ...` entry.

Then no you can run just the application `foo.jar` itself.

To automate such dependencies, my personal preference is using `maven`. (`gradle` is popular too.)

Comment: The foo,jar, that I got from a third party, is in this format. foo.jar and then a lib folder. There is no META-INF file though.

Comment: I was hoping that it is something trivial that I am missing. Surely I do not require to jump through hoops to run a basic java program ....