# How to solve a NoClassDefFoundError caused by ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to make an extension for [BlueJ](http://www.bluej.org) (this is a free `Java Development Environment` designed for beginners). The Extension should help the first year students in our school.
The extension has to be a JAR file, that I have to place in a folder where `BlueJ` can load it at `runtime`. My already written extension can be loaded from there and it works without any problem.

Now to the reason, for this question:
I want to integrate [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net) (this is a development tool to help programmers write Java code that adheres to a coding standard.) into my extension. So I put the `checkstyle jar` within my project and tried to use this library inside my code. If I now generate a jar and copy my extension into the `BlueJ` folder and start `BlueJ` out of eclipse I get the following error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/CheckstyleException   at
>   ch.ntb.sir.ntbbluejextension.NtbBlueJExtension.startup(NtbBlueJExtension.java:79)
>     at
>   bluej.extmgr.ExtensionWrapper.safeStartup(ExtensionWrapper.java:533)
>     at
>   bluej.extmgr.ExtensionWrapper.newExtension(ExtensionWrapper.java:209)
>     at
>   bluej.extmgr.ExtensionsManager.loadDirectoryExtensions(ExtensionsManager.java:164)
>     at
>   bluej.extmgr.ExtensionsManager.loadExtensions(ExtensionsManager.java:100)
>     at
>   bluej.extmgr.ExtensionsManager.getInstance(ExtensionsManager.java:61)
>     at bluej.Main.(Main.java:101)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)  at
>   bluej.Boot.bootBluej(Boot.java:348)   at bluej.Boot.main(Boot.java:175)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 14 more

At `NtbBlueJExtension.java:79` I make this initialization:

```
`codeAnalysisHandler = new CodeAnalysisHandler();`
```

Inside the `CodeAnalysisHandler` class I have imports from the `checkstyle libraries`:

```
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ConfigurationLoader;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.PropertiesExpander;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.TreeWalker;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AuditEvent;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AuditListener;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.Configuration;
```

My first though is, that there I should find the cause of my problem? But then I have no idea what to search and how to solve it.

I've added the jar in my project properties in eclipse.
The Jar is inside the project structure in my `lib` folder. `BlueJ` had no problem to load the `bluejext.jar` from the "lib" folder. The `bluejext.jar` comes from `BlueJ` and is required to write an extension for BlueJ.
I have this manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: ch.ntb.sir.ntbbluejextension.NtbBlueJExtension
Class-Path: lib/bluejext.jar lib/checkstyle-all.jar
```

I tried to google it, but found mostly information about how difficult it is to find the reason.

**EDIT 1:**
I unzipped my JAR file to look, if the `checkstyle-all.jar` is really inside my extension and there I found a file `.classpath`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/bluejext.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/checkstyle-all.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

**SOLUTION:**
Use Eclipse Kepler with the [fat jar plugin](http://fjep.sourceforge.net) (Neon was to new for the plugin) and export the project with ´Build Fat Jar´. After that the ´java.lang.ClassNotFoundException´ didn't appear anymore.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Make sure that your jar file contains checkstyle lib. Check this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033603/how-to-create-a-jar-with-external-libraries-included-in-eclipse) for more information.

Comment: @MinhHoàng I unzipped my extension JAR file and the checkstyle-all.jar is inside the lib folder. So this should be ok?

Comment: @MinhHoàng I edited my question with some new information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Java Document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html):

> The Class-Path header points to classes or JAR files on the local network, not JAR files within the JAR file or classes accessible over Internet protocols

If you want to include `checkstyle` in the extension jar, you have to explode it into the main jar. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150811/what-is-a-fat-jar) for more information.

[Here](https://github.com/hgminh95/bluej-ext-sample) is an example using Gradle.

Comment: Ok, i will give that a try.
But the bluejext.jar worked perfectly within my jar exactly the way I described. Is it possible that this solution with the "fatjar" is only necessary for some jar?

Comment: It is because bluejext.jar is provided by bluej, while checkstyle is not. I think it may work if you add checkstyle-all.jar to lib folder of bluej.

Comment: To be more details, bluej does not use the `bluejext.jar` inside your extension jar but the one in `lib` folder of bluej.

Comment: Ah! this explains why bluejext.jar works... 
I've added the checkstyle-all.jar in the lib folder in bluej (same directory like the bluejext.jar from bluej). It didn't worked. I think my code inside my jar doesn't find the checkstyle jar in that lib folder?

(I still trying to make this fat jar, but I never worked with gradle so I have to look into that first.)

Comment: Maybe bluej use custom code to load jar file, I am not sure about that. If you are not familiar with gradle, you can try maven assembly plugin (for Maven) or eclipse fat jar plugin (never use it though).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the plugin. In eclipse neon the plugin doesn't work. But probably in an older version. I give it a try. It sounds like less time-consuming than to look into maven / gradle.

Comment: It looks like it works if I use eclipse Kepler with the Fat Jar plugin. I don't get the Error message `ClassNotFoundException`. Now I have to handle some checkstyle specific exceptions, but that's an other problem.
Thanks for your help!