# Create a java API with dependencies without using runnable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I need to create a java API to be used in Neptune. This API connects to a MySQL database, query it and return the data in a JSONObject.

My question is how to create a jar that contains the functions to query DB and also the jdbc driver and JSON jars.

I did my research and found that this can be possible creating a runnable jar but this way it cannot be used externely as an API, am I wrong?

I found this other way that is creating a jar with its dependencies using OneJar, is this the best way? I think that i'm missing something because this should be a frequent problem for java developers that want to create API for external use.

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

[How to create a jar with external libraries included in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033603/how-to-create-a-jar-with-external-libraries-included-in-eclipse)

This does not answer my question because I don't want a runnable jar, just want to create an API that contains methods who need to connect MySQL DB and for that the API need to have the jar of jdbc driver.

If there is another way to make this API to connect MySQL without include jdbc driver, i'm all ears.

Comment: You can use Spring Boot to create a data service that connects to the database and publish it as an executable JAR: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/

Comment: What is neptune?

Comment: What build system and/or IDE are you using to develop? Gradle, Maven, IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse?

Comment: @Axel http://www.neptune-software.com/. I'm using Eclipse

Comment: @duffymo still need to include the JSON jar

Comment: @Raniz  I'm using Eclipse

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a jar with external libraries included in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033603/how-to-create-a-jar-with-external-libraries-included-in-eclipse)

Comment: I'd probably use [ProGuard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard). Though it's often used for much more complex situations like obfuscation and shrinking, it can also handle such simple use cases.

Comment: There's a Maven plugin that creates a JAR with all dependencies in it.