# How do I include all Java dependencies (from the lib folder) into one jar file instead of having the main jar file along with a lib folder?

Tags: java, jar

Right now the folder contents looks like this:

```
lib (folder)
WebAPI.jar
```

I would like:

```
WebAPI.jar (with lib somehow included in WebAPI.jar)
```

By the way I'm using Netbeans.

Comment: Use the maven-assembly-plugin with the prefabricated _jar-with-dependencies_ descriptor: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html

Comment: You can also use the Eclipse IDE to package all your dependencies into one jar file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11033670/4147379