# # The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:annotation-config'

Tags: spring

It's working from IntelliJ IDE, But not working after creating jar and executing in my local,

Jdk - 1.5

spring - 3.1.0-RELEASE

**Caused by:** org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 33; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:annotation-config'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName"
                value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
        <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true"/>
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:log/dev.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false"/>
    </bean>

 </beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.logger</groupId>
    <artifactId>logger</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>logger</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <finalName>logger</finalName>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.TestLogger</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>assembly</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>      
       </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Tried with spring version in schema location as well.
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the way you have created the jar where in there is additional configuration needed for the external dependencies

Have a look this solution 
[How to create a jar with external libraries included in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11033603/1685051)

Comment: Thanks, Mudassar, for the quick reply. added pom.xml, 
Can you please let me know what could be the additional configuration during build