# Export a runnable JAR and include .so native library

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, jar, export

I'm writing a java application (on Linux OS) which accesses the webcam and display a video on a JPanel. I'm using openCV libraries in order to obtain it (also because I would like to add some image processing code).
I followed [this guide](http://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/01-installing-opencv-for-java.html) to compile the openCV library for Java

and the only way I could make it work was by creating an user library linked to the folder where I have the corresponding jar file.
(I tried to directly import the jar file but I have some runtime exception, so I gave up).

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hR0I.png) is my situation.
Now I have a working application (if I execute it from within Eclipse), and I want to export it as a single jar (or something executable outside Eclipse). I tried to achieve this by selecting [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RpXk.png) options.

The problem is that now I want test if the jar works by executing the following command from terminal (where Untitled.jar is the name of the exported code):

```
java -jar Untitled.jar
```

but I receive this error (I bolded the main problem):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
>   **Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java331 in
>   java.library.path**   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)  at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)    at
>   myRefreshTest.Main.main(Main.java:8)

opencv_java331 is the name of the .so library generated after building openCV for Java (opencv_java331.so)

I tried several way to export my program, also by selecting the 3rd option in the Eclipse export popup ("Copy required libraries into sub-folder next to the generated JAR) and then executing

```
java -cp Untitled_lib/opencv-331.jar  -jar Untitled.jar
```

but terminal returns this error:

> **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no
>   opencv_java331 in java.library.path**     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)  at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)    at
>   myRefreshTest.Main.main(Main.java:8)

So, the problem is clear, it can't find the openCV .so library.
I tried to use also option -Djava.library.path but it is not working (or at least I'm not using it properly)
I'm not a Java expert and I cannot understand how to fix this problem. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: I successfully made it working by following these steps:  

1) Export the project as "Runnable JAR library" by selecting the option "Package required libraries into generated JAR"  
2) Create a new folder and paste inside the .so library (libopencv_java331.so)  
3) Execute the jar with the command `java -Djava.library.path=./native/lib/ -jar Untitled.jar`  

The solution works, but I would like to know if there is a way to make the jar execute without this workaround...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a jar with external libraries included in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033603/how-to-create-a-jar-with-external-libraries-included-in-eclipse)