# How to permanently include an external library in an Eclipse project (Java)? So that when porting it to another computer, it's still there

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, gson

I've added the GSON library to Eclipse ([following this tutorial](https://medium.com/programmers-blockchain/importing-gson-into-eclipse-ec8cf678ad52)) and using `import com.google.gson.*;`

I'd like to put the GSON library inside the project so that when opened in a different computer, it already has the library. Right now the Java class that uses the GSON lib fails if the package is not installed.

Comment: Are you using any kind of builder such as Maven on your project? If yes, this should be really trivial. If you don't, then may I suggest you to take an hour or so to convert your project so you won't have to have to deal anymore with that kind of problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033603/how-to-create-a-jar-with-external-libraries-included-in-eclipse

Comment: I upvoted @minizibi 's answer, but I stick with my solution if you want to have something not depending on your IDE.

Comment: @DamCx no, I haven't built the project yet, I'm just running the project from Eclipse.

Comment: @minizibi okay, so I need to export the whole project as a JAR file in order to do that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You had the simplest answer already: "put the GSON library inside the project."

Comment: I was asking **how** do I put the GSON library inside the project. So that it stays there when porting the source code. I don't know how to do it.