# ClassNotFoundException: BASE64EncoderStream when I run jar

Tags: java, dependency-management, classnotfoundexception

If I work in eclipse the problem does not occur, but if I create the jar and try to run it I get this error.
Why?

this is where I get this error:

```
    try {
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(KEY.getBytes(), CriptAlgorithm);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CriptAlgorithm);
        if (op.equals("C")) {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] enc = cipher.doFinal(val.getBytes("UTF8"));
            enc = BASE64EncoderStream.encode(enc);
            return new String(enc);
        }else {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] dec = BASE64DecoderStream.decode(val.getBytes());
            byte[] utf8 = cipher.doFinal(dec);
            return new String (utf8,"UTF8");
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**EDIT**:
In eclipse when I create the jar I have this options. I tried all three options but the problem persists

[image]

This is My Build Path
[image]

this is the java class:
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.util.BASE64EncoderStream

I don't understand why I have this error, the class is not external

Comment: `org.apache.geronimo.mail.util.Base64DecoderStream`? `com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream`? Other? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: You probably failed at adding the external dependency to your jar when packing it. There are a couple of options, probably listed in the export-to-jar-dialog in your IDE. Such as *"no libs, pack libs into jar, pack libs into folder next to jar"*. That is, provided you create the jar using your IDE.

Comment: can you expand your classpath and check for javax.mail-XX.jar?? specially explode the jar and check for the dependency

Comment: @trashgod com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.util.BASE64EncoderStream

Comment: Download the Jar from here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj/saaj-impl/1.3

Comment: @Yugansh why should i download the jar?
the program works if I launch it inside eclipse, it doesn't work when I use the generated jar...

Comment: did you checked exploding  your jar and check for the dependency jar inside it ? , it this jar is no there then you are not bundling into the main jar , so you need to download and add to your classpath

Comment: @Yugansh I think I have found the problem. If I try to launch the jar with this command i get the error : "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin\java.exe" -jar GAP-V.1.0.0.jar 
If i try to launch it with this command no error occurs : "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe" -jar GAP-V.1.0.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

> Updated answer as per the jar you mentioned in comments

The error suggest that there is this jar missing from your class path when you are running your jar , please try adding this to your project if maven based

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj/saaj-impl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
    <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

otherwise download the jar [Jar Details](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj/saaj-impl/1.3) and add to your library folder for classpath

Also its good if you follow this when building your jar [Build jar with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033603/how-to-create-a-jar-with-external-libraries-included-in-eclipse)

For Maven based project follow this for packaging [Maven Jar Packaging with Dependecy](https://crunchify.com/how-to-create-build-java-project-including-all-dependencies-using-maven-maven-resources-maven-dependency-maven-jar-plugin-tutorial/)